# Raster stretching on ImageMosaic with Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, stretch

I am trying to demo serving rasters over GeoServer.  I have created the store and the layer but the layer preview comes up all black.  The layer is queryable however so I know the data is accurate because I see the correct values when I click on the raster.

The raster values are single-band grayscale from 0 to 1.  How do I stretch the colors on these from black to white the same way they would be if loaded into QGIS or ArcMap?  Is it possible to change color ramp altogether to pseudocolor?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SLD Style, in particular a ColorMap in RasterSymbolizer to create a pseudo-color representation. See the documentation here:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#colormap

The rest of the page might be useful as well.